# Couchbase select reserved keyword named column

Tags: couchbase, sql++

In my couchbase query I am receiving error because "**Path**" is a reserved keyword.

```
select RawUrl, Path from couchbaseSample order by CreateTimeUtc desc

[{"code":3000,"msg":"syntax error - at Path"}
```

I tried using [Path] but did not work.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape reserved words using back ticks.

```
select RawUrl, `Path` from couchbaseSample order by CreateTimeUtc desc
```